# How to programmatically capture a webcam photo

Tags: python, video, ubuntu, webcam

What's the simplest way in Ubuntu 11.10 to programmatically guide (either from Bash or Python) the user to capture a webcam photo of themselves?

I can launch a simple app like Cheese, but I don't see an easy way to immediately detect or retrieve the photo it captures. I can also access and record the webcam stream directly via OpenCV, but I'd have to reinvent the GUI to communicate with the user.

Is there any kind of script that's a happy medium, where I can launch it, and it prints on stdout the filename of the image the user took?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install streamer`

Comment: See also: [How can I take camera images with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28418962/562769)

Comment: An ubuntu - CPP program to capture and extract frame and save as image file in the local folder.
* FFMPEG
* V4L2

https://github.com/abdullahfarwees/camera-frame-extracter

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to do this via Python, it looks like you have a few options. [The Pygame library has the ability to access cameras](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html).

If that's unsatisfactory, you can go much lower level and access the [Video 4 Linux 2 API](http://web.archive.org/web/20191030081801/http://www.voidcn.com:80/article/p-mgdhfohx-gc.html) directly using ioctl calls using [Python's fcntl library](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html).

Comment: Link for The Pygame library is wrong now. The requested URL /docs/tut/camera/CameraIntro.html was not found on the server.

Answer (score 39):

I like using pygame for that - 
it does not require you to open a Pygame SDL window, unlike when you want to use it to capture keyboard events, for example.

```
import pygame.camera
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(pygame.camera.list_cameras()[0])
cam.start()
img = cam.get_image()
import pygame.image
pygame.image.save(img, "photo.bmp")
pygame.camera.quit()
```

Though Pygame will only save uncompressed "bmp" files - you may want to combine it with PIL to write to other formats.

Comment: By now, pygame can save to png, jpg, tiff and bmp. At least tose were the ones I tested. Just change the extension and pygame detects it.

Comment: pygame.camera.quit() doesn't work; use cam.stop() instead.