# Is there a version of SimpleCV to install with Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, simplecv

I just installed **SimpleCV Version 1.3 Superpack** and it installs **Python 2.7** and all the libraries included. I tried to run it, got this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "**G:\images.py**", **line 1**, in module
>   from SimpleCV import Camera
>   ImportError: No module named SimpleCV

Is there a version would work with **Python 3.5**?

I have **Windows 8.1 x64**, thanks!

Comment: For the record, I tried to `pip3 install simplecv` and then `2to3` on installed SimpleCV directory, but no luck... After fixing errors about a few missing modules I got an error which made me feel, like it's a not an easy thing to fix and I gave up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To my knowledge there is (not yet) a Python 3 version of SimpleCV.

But [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) runs under Python 3. Pre-compiled windows binaries can be found here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv

Comment: i have tried all that but nothing seems to work, I have been trying to access my webcam and its not working, I tried pygame and opencv and simplecv , videocaptire, nothing is working, although It worked fine with Jave on eclipse, any suggestions ?

Comment: @MohamedGabr Is it a standard V4L webcam or are you using some special camera/library?

Answer (score 0):

To take pictures with your webcam try Pygame: [How to programmatically capture a webcam photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711946/how-to-programmatically-capture-a-webcam-photo)

I found that link very helpful, precisely jstbueno's comment.
**Excerpt from the site.**

```
enter code here

import pygame.camera
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(pygame.camera.list_cameras()[0])
cam.start()
img = cam.get_image()
import pygame.image
pygame.image.save(img, "photo.bmp")
pygame.camera.quit()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also pull it from Github and install it pretty easily.

git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git

Comment: That's the *OpenCV* library, not SimpleCV... and what's the benefit of grabbing it from a GitHub account rather than the OS package manager or Pip?